# CefSharp: Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I get the exception `CefSharp: Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime`. I found similar questions with `CefSharp.Core.dll` or `CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll`, but in my case it is with `CefSharp.Core.Runtime`, without `dll`.

I installed `CefSharp.OffScreen 96.0.180.0` using nuget.

I installed the latest supported Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2022. I have all the [required files](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)). I followed [these steps](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies) (although the error in my case is with the `Core.Runtime`).

My code:

```
string url = "MY_URL";
using (var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url))
   {
      var initialLoadResponse = await browser.WaitForInitialLoadAsync(); <- ERROR!!!
      var html = await browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
      HERE_I_DO_SOME_STUFF_WITH_MY_HTML;
   }
```

It breaks when I try to get the initial load response.

I also get the messages

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in CefSharp.OffScreen.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
```

in the console.

My app is .net462.

I looked at several questions in SO and none of them worked. The only one I didn't try is the `x64` vs `x86` solution because I don't understand the consequences (if I change it, will it affect to the other developers? will it compile in the Azure server?). The only thing I did here is adding the following lines in the `csproj` file:
[image]

I have these files in `bin/Debug`:

[image: Debug folder]

I have these files in `bin/Debug/x64`:

[image: x64 folder]

The folder `bin/Debug/x86` looks exactly the same as `bin/Debug/x64`.

I had previously installed `CefSharp` in a POC in the same solution, in a project in `.net6` and it worked without any issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which AnyCpu solution did you choose? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Comment: Where? I debug it with the "Any CPU". Sorry, I don't understand the question... :-(

Comment: Are you targeting AnyCpu? If yes then you need to tell .Net how to load the arch specific assemblies. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Comment: I already saw this page. There are 3 problems with it: 1) As I mention in the question, I am afraid to specify a specific target, because I don't know if this will affect the other people and/or the Azure server. 2) The Prefer 32-bits option appears disabled (I use VS 2022) and 3) I tried to select either target (x86 and x64) and in both cases I the application crashed before. Since I don't know what I do and I have the aforementioned concerns, I didn't go on trying this possibility. I'll give one more try, though...

Comment: Add a call to CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver() very early in your application. I'd suggest in Program.Main You don't need to change to platform or PlatformTarget.

Comment: I use `OwinStartup` and there is no main. I added it in `ConfigureApplication` and I still have the same problem... :-(

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/ instead.

Comment: The suggestion is based on the fact I use `Owin` or because I couldn't fix the problem? Just to know... Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Puppateer is better suited to be run from within asp Net.